# How to load stock icon Images?

Tags: java, icons, swt

I'm creating toolbar with icons, but i face one problem: can't find how to load stock icons for buttons like save, open, new, ...

I know how to use my icons, but i don't want to create my own or find somewhere and i like applications with stock system icons.

I'm looking for cross-platform solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's part of swing, but i'm using SWT for native look

Comment: I'm really interested in the answer to this. Have been searching for a solution some time ago without luck...

Comment: do you imagine that the 'stock' icons are look and feel dependent?  which other applications use the stock icons?

Comment: @Randy The most of applications in Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides, [Dispaly.getSystemImage()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UsingSystemIconImage.htm), it is not currently supported by SWT (according to this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=93606)). You can look at the patches attached to the bug report and modify code for your platform to extract other icons/resources.

Answer (score -1):

See [Eclipse icons](http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/). They are licensed under EPS, so free to use.

Comment: They aren't stock system icons and if wanted icons gallery i would have asked for that :)

Comment: Your question is purely worded. It didn't say anything about system icons, nor about your use of SWT.

Comment: SWT is in TAGS and i said "i like applications with stock system icons" if you did read carefully you would see that